# Django DRF - What's the use of serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been using Django for over 3 years now, but have never felt the need to use DRF. However, seeing the growing popularity of DRF, I thought of giving it a try.

**Serializing** is the concept I find it most difficult. Consider for eg:- I want to save user details. Following is the user related models.

```
class Users(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'MALE'),
        ('F', 'FEMALE'),
        ('O', 'OTHERS'),
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=1, blank=True,
                              null=True)


class UserAddress(models.Model):
    ADDRESS_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Permanent'),
        ('Cu', 'Current'),
        ('Co', 'Correspondence')
    )
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
    address_type = models.CharField(choices=ADDRESS_TYPE_CHOICES,
                                    max_length=255)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name='uaddress')


class UserPhone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name='uphone')


class UserPastProfession(models.Model):
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=10)  # BusinessMan, software Engineer, Artist etc.
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, related_name='uprofession')
```

I'm getting all the user details bundled in one POST endpoint.

```
{
    'first_name': 'first_name',
    'middle_name': 'middle_name',
    'last_name': 'last_name',
    'gender': 'gender',
    'address': [{
        'line1': 'line1',
        'line2': 'line2',
        'address_type': 'address_type',
    }],
    'phone': ['phone1', 'phone2'],
    'profession': ['BusinessMan', 'Software Engineer', 'Artist']
}
```

Without using DRF, I would have made a `Users` object first, linking it with `UserAddress`, `UserPhone` and `UserPastProfession` object.

How the same could be done using DRF? I mean `validating`, `serializing`, and then saving the details. How serializers.py file will be look like?

Comment: Have you looked at the DRF quick start guide and its section on serializers (and read up on nested serializers)? Do you have a specific problem you're having writing a serializer, as at the moment this could be interpreted as "Can someone write me a serializer for my code".

Comment: @JonClements - I've tried writing a serializer but fail to understand the use of it, when the same thing can be done using the raw Django commands (with less code). I'm not asking anyone to code for me, but just wanted to compare and understand the usage of the same.

Comment: And it can't be always nested. Can it be? What if the phone, address and profession details are being POSTed over different endpoints, with the associated userid. Will be still be a nested serialzers?

Comment: Well - a serializer works *both* ways... so you might want to construct a JSON response of name, list of phone numbers and addresses for instance... so you create a serializer that describes how that looks and you can GET and POST that format of data and the models are automatically validated and created/updated on a successful POST or the structure of your response is automatically based from a single object.

Comment: Think of it this way - you could potentially handle everything you wanted for POST requests (check necessary values are present/aren't duplicates/validate meeting criteria etc/then creating/updated a model...) without using a django `Form`... Although it'd be odd to not do so

Comment: One scenario:- If I've 3 POST endpoints (1: POST user data. 2: POST user phone details, 3. POST user address) and 1 GET endpoint that returns all the user details(basic data, address, phone), do I need to make 4 different serializers, 3 for POST data and 1 for GET?

Comment: In your current setup - yes. However, you'd have a single endpoint and serializer (let's call it "contact") that'd on a GET return the data, or on a POST (which would (optionally) contain user details/phone details/address details) which would then get deserialized and validated and your user data, phone, address details updated in the relevant models for you. Then you can use the HTTP "verbs" to use POST to append data or PUT to replace data or whatever's appropriate. And sending a DELETE could delete the user data or addresses etc...

Comment: Great!! Understood its importance. One last query. The thing you mentioned that if there's a single endpoint, it too is possible. How? Via Nested Relationships?

Comment: Yeah, so you'd have 3 serializers for user data, phone data and address data (so it knows how to work with those), then a single serializer that contains a  user data serializer and then a reference to the phone and address data serializers saying that `many=True` and then you can automatically handle GET/POSTing user data with zero or more items of address/phone data.

Comment: One quick question. Is it possible for a serializer to `exclude` some fields from GET and include/optional in POST request?

Comment: I believe so - off the topic of my head fields can be declared "writeonly" which I think is the behaviour you want - it's in the docs... I'd suggest reading them thoroughly :p

Answer (score 23):

If you want to make your life easy, you will surely use it.

Serializers allow complex data such as querysets and model instances to be converted to native Python datatypes that can then be easily rendered into JSON,  XML or other content types. Serializers also provide deserialization, allowing parsed data to be converted back into complex types, after first validating the incoming data.

This gives you a generic way to control the output of your responses, as well as a ModelSerializer class which provides a useful shortcut for creating serializers that deal with model instances and querysets.

They save you from writing a lot of custom code. Let’s look at some examples.

Pretend we have an app that tracks a list of tasks that the user has to complete by a certain date. The Task model might look something like the following:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    due_date = models.DateField() 
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When the user requests those tasks, our app returns a response in the form of a JSON-serialized string. What happens when we try to serialize our Django objects using the built-in json library?

```
import json
task = Task.objects.first()
json.dumps(task)
```

We get a TypeError. Task is not JSON serializable. To bypass this, we have to explicitly create a dictionary with each of the attributes from Task.

```
json.dumps({
    'title': task.title,
    'due_date': task.due_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    'completed': task.completed
})
```

Serializing a Python object from a JSON string or from request data is just as painful.

```
from datetime import datetime 
title = request.data.get('title')
due_date = datetime.strptime(request.data.get('due_date'), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
completed = request.data.get('completed')
task = Task.objects.create(title=title, due_date=due_date, completed=completed)
```

Now, imagine having to follow these steps in multiple views if you have more than one API that needs to serialize (or deserialize) JSON data. Also, if your Django model changes, you have to track down and edit all of the custom serialization code.

Creating and using a serializer is easy:

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Task.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'due_date', 'completed')

# Serialize Python object to JSON string. 
task_data = TaskSerializer(task).data 

# Create Python object from JSON string.
task_data = TaskSerializer(request.data)
task = task_data.create()
```

If you update the Django model, you only have to update the serializer in one place and all of the code that depends on it works. You also get a lot of other goodies including (as you mentioned) data validation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: One thing I'd suggest is that u're calling `task_data.create` with no argument. While it should have `serializer.validated_data` passed. IMO it is a poor design decision by DRF to have to pass a member of the class from the outside. Anyway, just wanted to share this. Regards

Answer (score 3):

If I got you correctly, my answer is:

> It is not necessary to write one serializer for a model, even for method type (POST,GET etc.). You can pretty much create serializers for your model as much as you need and set fields you want to operate on. You can also set those different serializers as serializer_class property of your APIView class per each method.

I strongly recommend you to take some time to look at the [Django Rest Framework Tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

below is how your serializer can look.. but please go through this [DRF serializer realtionship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

```
from rest_framework.serializers import (
    ModelSerializer,
    PrimaryKeyRelatedField
)

class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the users models.. Please dont forget to import the model
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        field = "__all__"


class UserPhoneSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the users address model..
    Pass the previously created user id within the post.. serializer will automatically validate
    it
    """

    user_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Users.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = UserPhone
        field = "__all__"

class UserAddressSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the users address model..
    Pass the previously created user id within the post.. serializer will automatically validate
    it
    """

    user_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Users.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = UserAddress
        field = "__all__"


class UserPastProfessionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the UserPastProfession model..
    Pass the previously created user id within the post.. serializer will automatically validate
    it
    """
    user_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Users.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = UserPastProfession
        field = "__all__"
```